# Exported telerik report has different pdf formats in different machines?

Tags: c#, telerik

I have exported telerik report in PDF. The exported PDF has different dispaly formats in different machine. For Example: In one machine, the exported report has 4 pages while in other it has 1 page. I ahve the same versions of Adobe installed in both the machines. Is there any reason for this to happen??

Answer (score 1):

the situation that same function return different result indicate somethings depends on "**global state**"

something depend on machine environment such as shared configuration or..

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
```

what's the different between 2 pdf files (eg. font size, margin)

Comment: The difference is the number of pages. In my local solution, the whole page is exported in single page whereas in server, the exported page is divided into multiple pages, i.e some of the columns are moved to the next page.